# Transfer hour number to date in NC file using R

Tags: r, date

I try to read a NC data using ncdf soft-package, in which I read the time dimension.

```
ti<-get.var.ncdf(nc,varid="time")
nc$dim$time$unit
"hours since 1-1-1 00:00:0.0"
```

So the number is start from 1-1-1 00:00:00 with each hour

I am wondering how to transfer it to date, like 1/1/2003

Thank you

Comment: If you can find out when 1-1-1 is use something like as.POSIXct("2001-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "GMT") + ti *3600 no one could guess that start date though often you csn cross check to increase confidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
hours <- 17645592 # e.g. this is the number of hours from 01-01-01 to 2014-01-01
DATE <- as.POSIXct(x='01-01-01',tz='GMT',format='%Y-%m-%d') + (hours*60*60)
# > DATE
#[1] "2014-01-01 GMT
```